# java web start application won't run

Tags: java, web, java-web-start

I wrote a simple program in java using eclipse. The program requires disk access (read and write) and some internet access. I want to create a web start application out of it, so I downloaded netbeans. I imported the project and ran it with netbeans. Everything worked. After that I right clicked the project, went to web start => I selected local Execution, selected an icon and signed it with my own created key. (I didn't select "Allow offline").

After that I hit f11 and the project build. I went to the project folder and opened the dist folder and dragged everything to my desktop (C:\Users\teddy\Desktop\host). I double clicke dlaunch.jnla and then I got the error: Unable to laucn hthe application
I clicked details. The error looks like this:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: file:/C:/Users/teddy/workspace/facebooker/dist/facebooker.jar
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I also used JaNeLA to chech the jnla file, this is the output:

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


Report for file:/C:/Users/teddy/Desktop/host/launch.jnlp

Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
XML encoding not known, but declared as UTF-8
Codebase + href 'file:/C:/Users/teddy/workspace/facebooker/dist/launch.jnlp' is not equal to actual location of 'file:/C:/Users/teddy/Desktop/host/launch.jnlp'.
Optimize this application for off-line use by adding the <offline-allowed /> flag.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'facebooker.jar'.
The resource download at facebooker.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for facebooker.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/restfb-1.6.14.jar'.
The resource download at lib/restfb-1.6.14.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/restfb-1.6.14.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/restfb-1.6.14.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/restfb-1.6.14.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for '007.jpg'.
Icon loading & use can be optimized by specifying the width and height for 007.jpg
Report for file:/C:/Users/teddy/workspace/facebooker/dist/jnlpcomponent1.jnlp

Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
XML encoding not known, but declared as UTF-8
Optimize this application for off-line use by adding the <offline-allowed /> flag.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'lib/forms-1.3.0.jar'.
The resource download at lib/forms-1.3.0.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at lib/forms-1.3.0.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the lib/forms-1.3.0.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/forms-1.3.0.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
```

#

Does anyone knows what's going on here?

The JNLP file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="file:/C:/Users/teddy/workspace/facebooker/dist/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>facebooker</title>
        <vendor>teddy</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>facebooker</description>
        <description kind="short">facebooker</description>
    <icon href="007.jpg" kind="default"/>
</information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="facebooker.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/restfb-1.6.14.jar"/>
<extension href="jnlpcomponent1.jnlp"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: `Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'` That means some elements are in the wrong order.  What is the content of the JNLP?

Comment: added the jnlp to the post.

Comment: If you want to access the local hard drive then you need to sign your jar file.  You can use a self-signed cert for testing.

Comment: But I signed my application. Tried everything unsigned, self-signed and custom signed :(

Comment: Move `<update check="always"/>` to after the `security` element.  That might fix the 'invalid content' message. `<application-desc main-class="">` the `main-class` field should not be empty.

Comment: moved the line and set <application-desc main-class=""> to ui.ui.java (don't know if this is correct, the main class is ui.java and inside package ui). Now I'm getting the "found unsigned entry in resource"